# Why i can't create a new project from github using composer?

Tags: codeigniter, github, project

I have created a new repository on GitHub. I have used GitHub Desktop to commit all files. All is done. But I can't create a new project with Composer.
Here is my repository: 
https://github.com/xttrust/CodeIgniter-HMVC-EXTRA

I have tried to create a new project like this:

```
composer create-project xttrust/CodeIgniter-HMVC-EXTRA
```

I get this error in GitBash:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package xttrust/codeigniter-hmvc-extra with stability stable.

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Comment: Have you submitted it to [Packagist](https://packagist.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652068/why-i-cant-create-a-new-project-from-github-using-composer/54665714#comment96100808_54652068):

> Have you submitted it to [Packagist](https://packagist.org/)?

I had to merge it with Packagist, and it then worked.

Answer (score 0):

No issue as the error is correct. Try searching Packagist. You will need to submit your github repo https://github.com/xttrust/CodeIgniter-HMVC-EXTRA